# how to install wordcloud package in python?

Tags: python, word-cloud

```
pip install wordcloud
  File "<ipython-input-130-12ee30540bab>", line 1
    pip install wordcloud
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

This is the problem I am facing while using `pip install wordcloud`.

Comment: Run `pip install wordcloud` in your [*shell*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_(computing)), not in Python.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`pip` is a tool used for installing python packages. You should not use this command inside the python interactive shell.

Instead, exit out of it and write `pip install wordcloud` on the main shell.

Answer (score 1):

Or use following command from jupyter notebook/lab:

```sh
!pip install wordcloud
```

Answer (score 0):

missing the ! in front of pip if doing it in python instead of shell